# Magento 2 Category attribute not creating

Tags: magento2, category

I am using below Script it's working in my local but its not working in my Live Sever

**`InstallData.php`**

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

/**
 * @codeCoverageIgnore
 */
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    /**
     * EAV setup factory
     *
     * @var EavSetupFactory
     */
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    /**
     * Init
     *
     * @param EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
     */
    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.ExcessiveMethodLength)
     */
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        /** @var EavSetup $eavSetup */
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.0') < 0){
            $eavSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category :: ENTITY, 'test', [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => 'Test',
                        'input' => 'textarea',
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 110,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                        'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
                        'group' => 'General Information',
                        "default" => "",
                        "class"    => "test",
                        "note"       => "test"
            ]
            );
            $eavSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category :: ENTITY, 'test1', [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => 'test1',
                        'input' => 'textarea',
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 120,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                        'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
                        'group' => 'General Information',
                        "default" => "",
                        "class"    => "test1",
                        "note"       => "test1"
            ]
            );
            $eavSetup -> addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category :: ENTITY, 'test2', [
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'label' => 'test2',
                        'input' => 'textarea',
                        'required' => false,
                        'sort_order' => 130,
                        'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                        'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                        'is_html_allowed_on_front' => false,
                        'group' => 'General Information',
                        "default" => "",
                        "class"    => "test2",
                        "note"       => "test2"
            ]
            );
        }

    }
}
```

**`Error : Attribute with attributeCode "test" does not exist.`**

Comment: have you run upgrade command?

Comment: YEs it's working my local not working live

Comment: have you check in your live module etc/module.xml file version?

Comment: what i need to check

Comment: <module name="Namespace_Module" setup_version="1.0.0">

Comment: have you run command in live ?

Comment: for data-upgrade i got this error setup:upgrade [--keep-generated] [--magento-init-params="..."]

Comment: for this command i got error sudo php bin/magento setup:db-data:upgrade above error